# (python-telegram-bot) How to resize button using button_row

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to resize `KeyboardButton` in my telegram bot. I'm using **Python-Telegram-Bot** wrapper for my bot. I found `button_row` option ([docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.replykeyboardmarkup.html#telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup.from_row)), but I don't understand where I should paste it.

Code:

```
def start(update, context):

    custom_keyboard = [['top-left', 'top-right'],
                      ['bottom-left', 'bottom-right']]
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text(text="Custom Keyboard Test", reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`button_row` is the first positional argument accepted by `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`.  In your case, you're providing `custom_keyboard` as this argument; which is correct.

What you may be looking for is the `resize_keyboard` argument, which according to that page you linked accepts a boolean:

> Requests clients to resize the keyboard vertically for optimal fit (e.g., make the keyboard smaller if there are just two rows of buttons). Defaults to false, in which case the custom keyboard is always of the same height as the app’s standard keyboard. Defaults to `False`

I appreciate this might not be what you mean, but if you want this behaviour, then update this line in your code to:

```
reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard, resize_keyboard=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful, but I want to resize button by height, but I can't find height parameter

Comment: @CODE I'm not sure this is possible. [this github issue](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/196), although it relates to the node client, suggests you can't provide custom sizes. Some quick searching throws nothing else up :-(